# PHP libcurl socks5 not working

Tags: php, libcurl, telegram-bot, socks

I try to connect to socks5 proxy using libcurl, however I receive the answer *SOCKS: authentication failed*. I also tried to connect to the proxy server through a Powershell script with cURL – it works, so the proxy server is available and my login and password are correct. I tried a lot of solutions... But connection via PHP-script still does not work.

PHP version – 5.4, cURL version – 7.19. What can I do?

**[UPDATE]** Here is my current code. I want to send message with my Telegram bot :)

```
    $proxy = '<hostname>:<port>';
    $proxy_auth = '<username>:<password>';

    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<botID>/sendMessage?'.'chat_id='.$chat_id.'&parse_mode='.$parse_mode.'&text='.'test';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy_auth);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    echo $error;
    echo $curl_scraped_page;
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Maybe your curl configuration doesn't trust https connection? try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)`

Comment: Try adding : 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $password);`

Comment: I would upgrade to curl 7.21.7 or above then you can use the newer `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'socks5://bob:marley@localhost:12345');` option directly

Comment: @JackSkeletron Unfortunately this does not help

Comment: @xanadev I tried but it does not work, too

Comment: @MrHeelis not sure that I can upgrade curl version. Is there any guide for that (for Windows Server)?

Comment: Download newer PHP version and get the php_curl.dll from the ext folder and replace it (after taking backup) http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: if you want to use the result of your query i guess you should add this :   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`
`curl_setopt($this->curlInstance, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);`

Comment: @xanadev I was going to mention that too at some point :-)

Comment: @MrHeelis trying to narrow it down lol

Comment: OK guys I have updated my code now :) This code should send message to the Telegram bot via socks5 proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete answer for anyone else having the same issue.

```
//Curl setup
$url = "https://google.com";
$proxy = "10.23.2.2:8080";
$password = "username:secret_passowrd";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

//proxy's address
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//proxy's password
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $password);

//in order to follow redirects.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//in order to use the result of the query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//run query
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
echo $error;
echo $curl_scraped_page;
curl_close($ch);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code doesnt work too (_SOCKS : authentication failed_)... and I can't understand why. Сan the proxy server name be a reason of problem? It's look like `ex.example.com`

Comment: $password should be like `username:passowrd`

Comment: Yes, I know and did it

Comment: Unfortunately yes :(

Comment: i've got the same code and it's working, what about that API you're using, don't you need authentication as well, i mean API_KEY or something like that.

Comment: This code does not work even with url https://google.com :) So I think that the main reason of problem is my proxy server... But I really can't understand why it works from Powershell and doesn't from PHP.

Thank you anyway :)